# How do I add new endpoints from Service Stack plugin?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am new to Service Stack, and am creating a plugin library for a Service Stack application we have.

Currently I have this class

```
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin {

    public void Register(IAppHost appHost){

         appHost.Routes.Add<MyPluginRequest>("/myendpoint", ApplyTo.Get);

    }
}
```

When I add a breakpoint and walk through it, the code it getting called and Ideally the endpoint is being registered. But when the metadata page pulls up, the endpoint isn't listed and I am unable to navigate to the /myendpoint url.

This is the service that I have but it doesn't seem to be visible to the Api.

```
public class MyPluginService : Service {

    public MyPluginResponse Get(MyPluginRequest request){

        ///... implementation details
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I added this code to the Register Function:

```
appHost.GetPlugin<MetadataFeature>().AddPluginLink("myendpoint/", "endpoint custom");
```

So it will appear on the MetaData page, but when navigating to the link I am still getting an error

> Unable to resolve service 'MyPluginRequest'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Routes.Add` API is only for registering custom routes for existing Services. If you want to dynamically register a Service you need to use `RegisterService<T>` API instead and specify the `serviceType`, e.g:

```
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin 
{
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.RegisterService<MyPluginService>("/myendpoint");
    }
}
```

The `AddPluginLink` only adds the link to the metadata page:

```
appHost.GetPlugin<MetadataFeature>()
    .AddPluginLink("/myendpoint", "My Custom Endpoint");
```